# WinDbg does not shows all first chance exceptions

Tags: windbg

I have an application, which sometimes fails. I run procdump and see some first chance exceptions like this:

```
[14:29:38] Exception: E06D7363.?AVCServicesMDException@@
[14:29:38] Exception: E06D7363.?AVCServicesMDException@@
[14:29:38] Exception: E06D7363.?AVCBaseException@@
[14:29:38] Exception: E06D7363.?AVCBaseException@@
```

I want to attach to process and analyze some of these exceptions. But have difficulties with setting WinDbg to handle it.

I run `.foreach(exc {sx}) {.catch{sxe ${exc}}}` & `sxe *` to catch all first chance exceptions and events.

But got nothing similar to exceptions from dump (written by procdump).